# I am unable to connect with the pwnedpasswords API from python

Tags: python, function, api

I am unable to connect with the pwnedpasswords API when I define a function and I get error "400", which is a bad request. I am using the following code:

```
import requests


def request_api_data(char):
    url = 'https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/' + char
    res = requests.get(url)
    print(res)


request_api_data('123')
```

However, when I use this code without function then I get a response of "200" which is a good response.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/' + 'CBFDA'
res = requests.get(url)
print(res)
```

I don't understand why it becomes a bad request when I try to make it a function.

Comment: Does the problem occur when you use same url?

Comment: `'123' != 'CBFDA'`... Tested with `curl`... `123` gives a 400 ("_The hash prefix was not in a valid format_")

Comment: Please be more specific in your title, this one is too general

Comment: Hi! Your fail example is calling with '123', but if you put in 'CBFDA' will it fail? your not-failing/not-function example is using CBFDA, but will that fail if you pass it '123'?

Comment: Yes, I checked when I use "CBFDA" in the upper function, then it works... and the lower code gets a "400" error when I replace "CBFDA" with "123". So, I guess this is because 123 is not a valid hash prefix as @BrunoMello answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the 123, if you try CBFDA in the first code it will work, it gives this error with 123:

"The hash prefix was not in a valid format"

This happens because 123 is not a valid hash prefix